# Failed to download repository information 12.10

Tags: 12.10

Can't update software in 12.10. Get the "Failed to download repository information" with the following below. Tried searching with these responses, but to no avail. Any ideas?

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: you might try by changing to other server.

Answer (score 1):

As I know it means that this ppa is offline or not working. So you have to delete this PPA by ppa-purge or by gui tool Y PPA manager

To install Y PPA manager:

***sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager***

***sudo apt-get update***

***sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager***

And then find Gwibber PPA and remove it.

P.S. But Gwibber ppa is have to work.